# How one extends JNA interface mappings? (Java)

Tags: java, mapping, jna

User32 interface (platform library) is missing some WinAPI functions, so I tried extending it:

```
package myapp
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32API

public interface User32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32 {
    myapp.User32 INSTANCE
    boolean IsWindow(W32API.HWND hWnd)
}
```

But then calling `myapp.User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(..)` results in `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method FindWindow() on null object`

Comment: When you *do* initialize `INSTANCE`, you should ensure you do it in the same fashion as the parent interface does, i.e. supply W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS to the `Native.loadLibrary()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `IsWindow` is correct (I am using an identical declaration in my current project.)

Most likely you are failing to initialise `INSTANCE`.